# Búsqueda insensible a acentos en mongoose

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose

Quiero hace una búsqueda a la base de datos de MongoDB, pero los datos se encuentra registrados con acento.

Por ejemplo si busco "agustin" y está registrado en la bd como "Agustín" no lo encuentra por el acento en el "í".

¿Alguien sabe si es posible que mongoose haga ese tipo de consultas, donde sea indiferente a los acentos?

Sé que se puede hacer la búsqueda insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero este caso es diferente.

```
    {
      $match: {
        "text": {
          $regex: new RegExp(word, 'i')
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Algo como esto? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647710/12189493

Comment: No hay una forma nativa en MongoDB para lo que quieres. Sólo aplicando un patrón específico como opción de búsqueda podrás lograrlo. Sin embargo, te pregunto: siendo `Agustín` y `Agustin` nombres totalmente diferentes, ¿Qué sentido tiene realizar una búsqueda por un campo tan variable y susceptible a errores?. Tal vez debas aplicar un patrón de búsqueda más complejo, lo que implica añadir una capa adicional de complejidad.

Comment: Otra opción,  que sólo funciona en Atlas, es definir índices personalizados que permitan aprovechar la capacidad de MongoDB para hacer *match* sin importar la acentuación (caracteres diacríticos). Puedes leer sobre estos [índices personalizados](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/diacritic-insensitive/) en la documentación de Atlas. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio por tu respuestas, la opción que me funcionó fue crear indices en MongoDB :)